# Помогите, не могу создать <li>, в ul , и что-бы из масива элемент , вставлялся в li как текст

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const ingredients = [
  'Potatoes',
  'Mushrooms',
  'Garlic',
  'Tomatos',
  'Herbs',
  'Condiments',
];
const itemEl = [];
const listEl = document.querySelector("#ingredients");

ingredients.map(ingredient => {
  const element = document.createElement("li");
  element.textContent = ingredient;
element.classList.add("item");

itemEL.push(element);
console.log(element);
});
listEl.append(itemEl);
console.log(itemEl);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Task 2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/common.css" />
    <style>
      .item {
        font-weight: 500;
      }

      .item:not(:last-child) {
        margin-bottom: 8px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><a href="index.html">Go back</a></p>

    <ul id="ingredients"></ul>

    <script src="js/task-02.js" type="module"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Я в js не силен, но скажу что в вашем html коден нет элемента li может поэтому ваш js код не срабатывает

Comment: itemEl   !== itemEL

Comment: там li  с помощью js додается

Answer (score 0):

`itemEl` !== `itemEL`

---

```js
const ingredients = [
  'Potatoes',
  'Mushrooms',
  'Garlic',
  'Tomatos',
  'Herbs',
  'Condiments',
];
const itemEl = [];
const listEl = document.querySelector("#ingredients");

ingredients.map(ingredient => {
  const element = document.createElement("li");
  element.textContent = ingredient;
  element.classList.add("item");

  itemEl.push(element);  
  listEl.append(element);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Task 2</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/common.css" />
  <style>
    .item {
      font-weight: 500;
    }
    
    .item:not(:last-child) {
      margin-bottom: 8px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p><a href="index.html">Go back</a></p>

  <ul id="ingredients"></ul>

  <script src="js/task-02.js" type="module"></script>
</body>

</html>
```